# regex to find characters but exclude some words that have that characters

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find all occurences of **ue** and replace it with **ü**, but not for occurences like **tuell**. Reason is that german words like *Aktuell* should not be *Aktüll* afterwards. I tried different approaches with lookahead and lookbehind but could not get it working. I used https://regex101.com/ to test the expression. focus is on finding via regex, replacing via PHP preg_replace is not an issue.

Comment: Try `ue(?!ll)` if the point is to match `ue` not followed with `ll` substring.

Comment: yes, that would work. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting my answer if it proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a `(?!ll)` negative lookbehind to make sure the next 2 chars are `ll` right after `ue`:

```
ue(?!ll)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/X3IZnk/1)

See [more details about lookarounds here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).